# Python list formatting with JSON

Tags: python, json

I'm a newbie in Python trying to turn information from an Excel file into JSON output.

I'm trying to parse this Python list:

```py
value = ['Position: Backstab, Gouge,', 'SumPosition: DoubleParse, Pineapple']
```

into this JSON format:

```py
"value": [
      {
        "Position": [
          "Backstab, Gouge,"
        ]
      },
      {
        "SumPosition": [
          "DoubleParse, Pineapple"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Please note:

This list was previously a string:

```py
value = 'Position: Backstab, Gouge, SumPosition: DoubleParse, Pineapple'
```

Which I turned into a list by using re.split().

I've already turned the string into a list by using re.split, but I still can't turn the inside of the string into a dict, and the value from the dict into a list.

Is that even possible? Is it the case to format the list/string with JSON or previously prepare the string itself so it can receive the json.dump method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did `re.split` know not to turn your `value` into `['Position: Backstab', ' Gouge', ' SumPosition: DoubleParse', ' Pineapple']`?

Comment: Are you sure you want a list of two separate dicts inside the "value" list, rather than a single dict with two keys? Are you sure you want the e.g. "Position" list to have a single value, rather than splitting up on the commas?

Comment: @BenQuigley I had the string at first, then used `value = re.split(r'.(?=Position:|SumPosition:)', value)`. Does this answer your question (I'm not sure I understood it)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, because this is going to be parsed to JSON, and I had no idea how to work the string to be shown in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the list to achieve desired result.

```
d = {'value': []}
for val in value:
    k, v = val.split(':')
    tmp = {k.strip() : [v.strip()]}
    d['value'].append(tmp)

print(d)

{'value': [{'Position': ['Backstab, Gouge,']},
  {'SumPosition': ['DoubleParse, Pineapple']}]}
```

Comment: This solves my issue, thanks! This syntax is quite complex for a begginer like me, but I'll make sure to study it and understand everything it does, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way.

```
value = ['Position: Backstab, Gouge,',
         'SumPosition: DoubleParse, Pineapple']

dictionary_result = {}
for line in value:
    key, vals = line.split(':')
    vals = vals.split(',')
    dictionary_result[key] = vals
```

Remaining tasks for you: trim off empty strings from result lists like `[' Backstab', ' Gouge', '']`, and actually convert the data from a Python `dict` to a JSON file

Comment: Thanks, this solution is easily applicable to my issue as well! I really need to understand better the iterations over dictionaries and lists. Thank you!